# Run a Cron Job In Cpanel with CURL

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

I have a code in laravel, I want to setup a cron job in cpanel But I don't know how to. I saw several examples that has file name to cron, but I am using Laravel so how can I point this to URL route?

```
/usr/bin/curl https://example.com/cron_route
```

I am not sure is this correct method or I can do that in different way, well I canot use laravel artisan scheduler, I have all custom code and custom Controller.

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Make a CLI script! Why go through apache etc when you can just call the PHP directly? Unless it's on another server? But either way you could cURL from the CLI script

Comment: @delboy1978uk I want to run as a cron job Like everyday or every minute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this command**

```
   1 1 * * 0  /usr/bin/curl -m 120 -s https://example.com/cron_route &>/dev/null
```

Comment: what is 120? here? every 2 minutes?

Comment: Also Can I set this via Cron Job Cpanel UI?

Comment: Yes you can set it's 120 timing slot

Comment: @VikasKatariya Where can I fire this command inside my terminl in cpanel?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore as of 2023, might be better to use `wget` as per the other answer

Answer (score 3):

To add cronjob using command line, use this command

```
0 2 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/cron_script
```

See for reference :  https://crontab.guru/

Comment: If I want to set at every minute? then 1 * * * * will work?

Comment: Also Can I set this via Cron Job Cpanel UI?

Comment: Yes, you can. Search for the cron job tab in Cpanel.